# UIBarButton item two methods / IBAction

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a bottom toolbar button that contains a button which opens a `UIWebView *webView`

```
- (IBAction)rebateWebView:(id)sender {
       [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]]];
}
```

Now, after the webView loads I want to change the title of the button and when the button is tapped again I want the webView to disappear or, in essence, reload the firstviewcontroller.

I know how to change the title and have that working. My biggest problem is dropping the webView. I just can't wrap my head around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[self.webView removeFromSuperView];` will remove your `webView` from the super view, which is almost certainly your view controller's `self.view`.

Then depending on whether you still need it or not you may want to `nil` it out and/or `release` it if you are not using ARC.

If you are trying to "reload" the view controller instead (which is completely different from dropping `self.webView`, you can call `[self viewWillDisappear:NO]; [self viewWillAppear:NO];` if what you need is in those methods.

**Edit**

Jim's suggestion is also valid if you may want to re-show that `self.webView` in the future:

`self.webView.hidden = YES` to hide
`self.webView.hidden = NO` to show

Comment: self.webView.hidden = NO; 
will also work to hide the webView and it also allows me to flip back and forth between the views.